# Require Authentication to Checkout Subversion Repository

Tags: svn

I have a repository on a server, and for some reason it does not require any authorization to check out the code, but a commit does.

I see in /home/svn/project/conf/svnserve.conf the following lines:

```
# anon-access = none
# auth-access = write
```

But I assume the `#` means they are commented out, but removing them gives me an "option missing" SVN error.

How do I make it so you need credentials to check out, just as you do to make a commit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try something on the lines of the following for the `svnserve.conf` file:

```
[general]
anon-access=none
auth-access=write
password-db=passwd
authz-db=authz
realm=My Repository
```

The above config means:

```
No anonymous access
Authorized users have read/write access
Use the 'passwd' file (defined above)
Use the 'authz' file (defined above)
Give the realm a name
```

For more details, have a look [here](http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Subversion/Configuration) in section 1.4.